# Should non-migrated questions be flagged for a moderator?

Tags: support, migration, closed-questions, flags

I just noticed that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955156/can-i-publish-some-stackoverflows-content-on-my-personal-blog/955166#955166) is closed as "belongs on meta", but not migrated (I think migration wasn't available at that time). That's not a particularly  big problem in this case (there are similar questions around on Meta), but for the general case, should there be more questions of this kind: Is it of any use to flag such a question for mod attention? Can a moderator migrate a question that has already been closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can be.

A moderator can migrate the question by re-opening it and then closing it again for migration. Since diamond moderators can do this with a single vote the process is fairly simple.

Comment: Hey, new avatar! :) And thanks for the answer.